# remove substring from address containing word and the word after it

Tags: regex, postgresql, substring

I've been trying to work out this regex and I am only able to get half way there.

Imagine strings like this (Address)

```
White Lund Industrial Estate  Unit 11a Southgate
White Lund Industrial Estate  Suite 124 Southgate
White Lund Industrial Estate  flat A Southgate
```

which I want to be

```
White Lund Industrial Estate Southgate
White Lund Industrial Estate Southgate
White Lund Industrial Estate Southgate
```

There is a patterns which is, if `Unit`, `Flat`, `Suite` appear in the string, remove them and the word after them.

I am doing this in postgres, and so far I got to this:

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE(lower('White Lund Industrial Estate Unit 11 a Southgate'), 'unit\S*', '');
```

which gives me:

`white lund industrial estate  11 a southgate`

How do I tell the regex expression to also remove the word after it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
\s*\y(unit|flat|suite)\s+\S+
```

Also, you can make it case insensitive with an embedded flag option `(?i)`:

```
(?i)\s*\y(unit|flat|suite)\s+\S+
```

**Details**

- `(?i)` - embedded option making matching case insensitive (see [*Table 9-20. ARE Embedded-option Letters*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html))
- `\s*` - 0 or more whitespace chars
- `\y` - word boundary
- `(unit|flat|suite)` - either `unit`, `flat` or `suite` substring
- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespace chars
- `\S+` - 1 or more non-whitespace chars.

See a [PostgreSQL test](https://rextester.com/AHEOK84016):

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE(lower('White Lund Industrial Estate Unit 11a Southgate'), '\s*\y(unit|flat|suite)\s+\S+', '');
```

Or,

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE('White Lund Industrial Estate Unit 11a Southgate', '(?i)\s*\y(unit|flat|suite)\s+\S+', '');
```

Output:

[image]